# How to configure ODI to auto-increment rows for IKM Incremental Update

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I have question about Autoincrement ID for my 'dimension' and IKM: Incremental Update.

I have source table with only one column: SUPPLIER_NAME. It has 23 rows with suppliers name.

I have target table with two columns: SUPPLIER_ID, SUPPLIER_NAME

Next I want on SUPPLIER_ID create autoincrement ID for every new row and use IKM: increment update - where someone add new supplier I only want update table (add new rowe) and add for this supplier new ID (next value for autoincrement).

How can I do this?

I create sequence on DB like:

```
Create sequence autoinc start with 1  
increment by 1  
minvalue 1  
maxvalue 1000000;
```

In ODI I create sequence: 
AutoIncrementDIm --> Increment: 1, 
Native seuqence - native sequence name: autoinc

Next I create ODI mapping:

Source table (with one colum) map to target table (with ID and NAME).

Map supplier_name to supplier_name

For ID I use: #NFS_HD.AutoIncrementDim_NEXTVAL

In logical part I set integration type: Incremental Update
In physical part I set for IKM: IKM Oracle Merge

For my first running everthing it's ok. I have autoincrement from 1 to 23 for every supplier.

But when I have new rows with new supplier name in source table and run my mapping I get something like:

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrAOt.jpg)

New row (with new supplier) has 47 ID ... I think that s because sequence was running for every rows.

What I must change to correct or what it is the better solution to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the logical mapping, click on your `SUPPLIER_ID` target attribute. In the property pane in the Target tab, unselect the Update checkbox. It means that this attribute will not be used in the update query.

[image]

Also make sure that the `SUPPLIER_NAME` attribute is set as a key so the IKM use it to know when it should do an insert or an update.

Comment: Hi JeromeFr,

Thanks for reponse. It is working for only update new row - but when I use 'solution' like yours in first running - when I have empty table with supplier_id || supplier_name and I want running ETL I get id = 1 for every row ans supplier_name.

Must I have two etl process? One for first loading data in table and second for update only new rows?

Comment: Update: Your solution it is working when its only ONE new row - when I have 3 new row I get the same ID for this new rows.

Comment: When I use: 
#NFS_HD.AutoIncrementDim_NEXTVAL -- I get the same ID for new rows (I have 1-24 supplier, add new 3 suppliers and after etl I have three 25 ID for three new suppliers)
:NFS_HD.AutoIncrementDim_NEXTVAL -- I get higher ID for example now I have 1 - 24, 25, 25, 25 --- next I add two new suppliers and use etl and result like: 1-24,25,25,25,53,54.

Comment: Yes you need to use : and not #. : is binding in PL/SQL while # is for a substitution at ODI level. So for a set-based operation # will return the same value. : will returns different values. The fact it jumped from 1 to 24 is because Oracle sequences are not gapless.